# XSL to create nested list from flat tree problem

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-grouping

I need to be able to create nested lists from a flat tree. For example, the input might be something like this:

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">num1</list>
    <list level="1">num2</list>
    <list level="2">sub-num1</list>
    <list level="2">sub-num2</list>
    <list level="3">sub-sub-num1</list>
    <list level="1">num3</list>
    <p>text</p>
    <list>num1</list>
    <list>num2</list>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

and the output should be nested as follows:

```
<root>
<h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2
             <ol>
                <li>sub-num1</li>
                <li>sub-num2
                    <ol>
                        <li>sub-sub-num1</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>num3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

I've tried a few approaches but just can't seem to get it. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Note: I need to do this using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a nested tree structure from a path in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872067/creating-a-nested-tree-structure-from-a-path-in-xslt)

Comment: @Phrog: Not really. The tree there is defined by the structure a value. This uses node order and a depth attribute.

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer, which is simpler than that of @Flack (no calling of templates and no passing of parameters) and may be shorter than the answer of @Flack, (mine 66 lines, his 53, but his is much wider and requires horizontal scrolling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kListGroup" match="list"
  use="generate-id(
          preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::list)][1]
                   )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "list[preceding-sibling::node()[1][not(self::list)]]">

  <ol>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="listgroup" select=
     "key('kListGroup',
          generate-id(preceding-sibling::node()[1])
          )
          [not(@level) or @level = 1]
     "/>
  </ol>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "following-sibling::node()[not(self::list)][1]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="list" mode="listgroup">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="vNext" select=
     "following-sibling::list
            [not(@level > current()/@level)][1]
     |
      following-sibling::node()[not(self::list)][1]
     "/>

     <xsl:variable name="vNextLevel" select=
     "following-sibling::list
     [@level = current()/@level +1]
      [generate-id(following-sibling::list
            [not(@level > current()/@level)][1]
           |
             following-sibling::node()[not(self::list)][1]
                  )
      =
       generate-id($vNext)
      ]
     "/>

     <xsl:if test="$vNextLevel">
     <ol>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="listgroup"
        select="$vNextLevel"/>
     </ol>
     </xsl:if>
  </li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document (intentionally complicated to show that the solution works in many edge cases)**:

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">1.1</list>
    <list level="1">1.2</list>
    <list level="2">1.2.1</list>
    <list level="2">1.2.2</list>
    <list level="3">1.2.2.1</list>
    <list level="1">1.3</list>
    <p>text</p>
    <list>2.1</list>
    <list>2.2</list>
    <h2>text</h2>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">3.1</list>
    <list level="1">3.2</list>
    <list level="2">3.2.1</list>
    <list level="2">3.2.2</list>
    <list level="3">3.2.2.1</list>
    <list level="1">3.3</list>
    <list level="2">3.3.1</list>
    <list level="2">3.3.2</list>
    <p>text</p>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <h1>text</h1>
   <ol>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2<ol>
            <li>1.2.1</li>
            <li>1.2.2<ol>
                  <li>1.2.2.1</li>
               </ol>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </li>
      <li>1.3</li>
   </ol>
   <p>text</p>
   <ol>
      <li>2.1</li>
      <li>2.2</li>
   </ol>
   <h2>text</h2>
   <h1>text</h1>
   <ol>
      <li>3.1</li>
      <li>3.2<ol>
            <li>3.2.1</li>
            <li>3.2.2<ol>
                  <li>3.2.2.1</li>
               </ol>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </li>
      <li>3.3<ol>
            <li>3.3.1</li>
            <li>3.3.2</li>
         </ol>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p>text</p>
</root>
```

**or as displayed by the browser**:

## text

1. 1.1
2. 1.2

   1. 1.2.1
   2. 1.2.2

      1. 1.2.2.1
3. 1.3

text

1. 2.1
2. 2.2

### text

## text

1. 3.1
2. 3.2

   1. 3.2.1
   2. 3.2.2

      1. 3.2.2.1
3. 3.3

   1. 3.3.1
   2. 3.3.2

text

Comment: @Dimitre, you at least own me an upvote for the xml sample :))

Comment: @Flack: I don't have any problem upvoting your answer, but as I commented on @Alejandro's answer, it is difficult for me to clearly decide which of our three answers is the best. People shouldn't think one answer is better than the others, when it isn't. Therefore, I will upvote you if as result all three answers will have the same number of upvotes. Of course, this is the ideal case. Let's wait a little while, then we'll see.

Comment: I've just tried both Flack's and Dimitre's answers and both work really well. And best of all, I learned something new (I'd never used the current() function before). Thanks all!

Comment: I tried to do some numbers, but relative in XSlerator is too big. May be someone would profile all solutions?

Comment: @Jacqueline: You are always welcome. And thanks for the excellent question -- it was more fun than fiendish sudoku :)

Answer (score 6):

**It almost drove me mad, but I finished it. Took me almost 2 hours.**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list])]">
    <ol>
        <xsl:variable name="selfId" select="generate-id()"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="recurseItems"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            following-sibling::list
            [@level = 1 or not(@level)]
            [preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list]]
            [$selfId = generate-id(
                preceding-sibling::list[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::list])][1]
                )
            ]
            [not(position() = 1)]
            " mode="recurse"/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="recurseItems">
    <xsl:param name="nodes" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="nextStep" select="$nodes/following-sibling::*[1][self::list]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$nodes/@level and ($nodes/@level &lt; $nextStep/@level)">
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="$nodes"/>
                <ol>
                    <xsl:call-template name="recurseItems">
                        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nextStep"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$nodes/@level and ($nodes/@level > $nextStep/@level)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes" mode="create"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$nextStep">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes" mode="create"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="recurseItems">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nextStep"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not($nextStep)">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$nodes" mode="create"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list" mode="recurse">
    <xsl:call-template name="recurseItems"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list" mode="create">
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to a slightly more complicated document:**

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">1.1</list>
    <list level="1">1.2</list>
    <list level="2">1.2.1</list>
    <list level="2">1.2.2</list>
    <list level="3">1.2.2.1</list>
    <list level="1">1.3</list>
    <p>text</p>
    <list>2.1</list>
    <list>2.2</list>
    <h2>text</h2>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <list level="1">3.1</list>
    <list level="1">3.2</list>
    <list level="2">3.2.1</list>
    <list level="2">3.2.2</list>
    <list level="3">3.2.2.1</list>
    <list level="1">3.3</list>
    <list level="2">3.3.1</list>
    <list level="2">3.3.2</list>
    <p>text</p>
</root>
```

**It produces this result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>1.1</li>
        <li>1.2
            <ol>
                <li>1.2.1</li>
                <li>1.2.2
                    <ol>
                        <li>1.2.2.1</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>1.3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
    <ol>
        <li>2.1</li>
        <li>2.2</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>text</h2>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>3.1</li>
        <li>3.2
            <ol>
                <li>3.2.1</li>
                <li>3.2.2
                    <ol>
                        <li>3.2.2.1</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>3.3
            <ol>
                <li>3.3.1</li>
                <li>3.3.2</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
</root>
```

**Applied to your sample it also produces the correct result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2
            <ol>
                <li>sub-num1</li>
                <li>sub-num2
                    <ol>
                        <li>sub-sub-num1</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>num3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

Comment: A deserved +1 for an answer to an exceptionally difficult question.

Answer (score 4):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kListByParent"
             match="list"
             use="concat(generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                                        [not(self::list)][1]),
                         '+',
                         generate-id(preceding-sibling::list
                                        [current()/@level > @level][1]))"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="list[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::list]"/>
    <xsl:template match="list">
        <xsl:variable name="vListMark"
                      select="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1])"/>
        <ol>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kListByParent',
                                             concat($vListMark,'+'))"
                                 mode="makeLi">
                <xsl:with-param name="pListMark" select="$vListMark"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="list" mode="makeLi">
        <xsl:param name="pListMark"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vChilds"
                      select="key('kListByParent',
                                  concat($pListMark,'+',generate-id()))"/>
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="$vChilds">
                <ol>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$vChilds"
                                         mode="makeLi">
                        <xsl:with-param name="pListMark"
                                        select="$pListMark"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <h1>text</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2
            <ol>
                <li>sub-num1</li>
                <li>sub-num2
                    <ol>
                        <li>sub-sub-num1</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>num3</li>
    </ol>
    <p>text</p>
    <ol>
        <li>num1</li>
        <li>num2</li>
    </ol>
    <h2>text</h2>
</root>
```

**Note**: The use of `current()` XSLT function in `xsl:key/@use`

Comment: +1 for a good answer -- it is very difficult to say that one of the answers is better than any other.

Comment: @Dimitre: You are right! I think we already answer this but I can't find the question...

Comment: +1. It was another WebStorm bug. I already hate this IDE. Removing previous comment.

Comment: @Flack: Why don't you try [XSelerator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xselerator/)?

Comment: @Alejandro, UI's bad and some poblems with Win 7. Like exception on start, no undo after file save, buggy autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a worked solution to a very similar problem in this paper

http://www.saxonica.com/papers/ideadb-1.1/mhk-paper.xml

Note: it's XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use XSLT 1.0.