# XSLT 1.0: Transforming flat structure to nested with Muenschian grouping: avoid creation of spurious copies

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am XSLT beginner, learning by example and by working on projects. Currently, I am working on creating grouped, nested structure from flat.

Consider this sample xml input:

```
<root>
    <a>First text</a>
    <b>Text</b>
    <c>More text in c tag</c>
    <d>There is even d tag</d>
    <a>Another "a" test.</a>
    <b>ěščřžýáíéúů</b>
    <b>More b tags</b>
    <c>One followed by c tag</c>
    <a>Last a tag</a>
    <b>This time only with b tag, but this goes on and on</b>
</root>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:key name="groupA" match="b|c|d" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[1])" />
  <xsl:key name="groupB" match="c|d" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::b[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <wrapperTest>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </wrapperTest>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|a"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|b"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupA', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('groupB', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output is:

```
<wrapperTest>
    <a>First text
      <b>Text
        <c>More text in c tag</c>
        <d>There is even d tag</d>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a>Another "a" test.
      <b>ěščřžýáíéúů</b>
      <b>More b tags
        <c>One followed by c tag</c>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a>Last a tag
      <b>This time only with b tag, but this goes on and on</b>
    </a>
</wrapperTest>
```

In the transformation I created are excessive copies created and I have no idea why. I guess that the isuue I am hiting upon is basic in its nature, but I cant figure it out.

The only limit for solution is, that preferably it should be in XSLT 1.0 (since the project is incorporated in `python` script with `lxml`). In the edge case, when this couldnt be achived with XSLT 1.0, I can accomodate for recent `saxon` version which removes any limitations ...

I have already looked at answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872067/creating-a-nested-tree-structure-from-a-path-in-xslt), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651257/xsl-to-create-nested-list-from-flat-tree-problem) and others, but most of them use either XSLT 2.0 or are very complicated for a beginner to knive through.

**Final note:** Ideally, proposed solution should be extensible in it nature, because the final form of my project should be also grouped by tag `<c>`, like so:

```
<wrapperTest>
    <a>First text
      <b>Text
        <c>More text in c tag
          <d>There is even d tag</d>
        </c>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a>Another "a" test.
      <b>ěščřžýáíéúů</b>
      <b>More b tags
        <c>One followed by c tag</c>
      </b>
    </a>
    <a>Last a tag
      <b>This time only with b tag, but this goes on and on</b>
    </a>
</wrapperTest>
```

Which I will happily do as learning excersize.

Comment: It seems like an advanced text book task for learning XSLT 2/3's `for-each-group group-starting-with` in a recursive function or template. As you say you have the option to use Saxon-C with Python bindings I would opt for that approach instead of fighting with keys or sibling recursion in XSLT 1. As for the current code, having two `xsl:template match="root"` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you very much for your comment and answer, however I would still prefer to know, or at least see solution in XLST 1.0. Reason being that I am working on several devices and only on one I have access to `saxon` without user control (my own personal device). Sadly, I dont know how to utilize Python bindongs for `saxon`, I have actually `java` platform HE which I run from terminal (when working on device that has access to it). I shouldve mention that I am beginner programmer too ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="b" match="b" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::a[1])" />
<xsl:key name="cd" match="c|d" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::b[1])"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <wrapperTest>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>
    </wrapperTest>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('b', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  
<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('cd', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Would you be kind to elaborate why `<xsl:apply-templates select="a"/>` and then cascading `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in specific node-matches works instead of approach I was using (define template aplications in match of the `root` node, at least I thought I was doing that ...) It would be greatly appreciated and hopefully informative for anybody wrestling with classic XSLT 2.0 issue using XSLT 1.0 ...

Comment: You want `a` nodes - and only `a` nodes - to be children of the root `wrapperTest` element - therefore you only apply templates to them at that point. Similarly, when you create an `a` node, you only want the trailing `b` nodes to be its children. --- Note that `<xsl:apply-templates/>` doesn't do anything in this example except copy text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive XSLT 2/3 `for-each-group group-starting-with` for all levels comes down to

```
<xsl:function name="mf:wrap" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="node()*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" group-starting-with="node()[node-name() = node-name($input[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="node(), mf:wrap(tail(current-group()))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>
        
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:wrap(*)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaj8